# Formly update templateOptions on click of button

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm new to formly, I want to change the templateOptions property based on value,
so below is my config

```
 formlyConfig.setType({
      name: 'phone',
      extends: 'maskedInput',
      defaultOptions: {

       templateOptions: {
          mask: '999-9999-9999'
        },
```

I want to change the mask to  mask: '999-999-9999' on a button click,

I tried to do this on onclick of button , but no change

```
                 formlyConfig.setType({
                    name: 'phone',
                    defaultOptions:{
                      templateOptions: {
                        mask: '999-999-9999'
                      },
                    }                     
                  })
```

;

Comment: I dont understand, can u explain

Comment: You want set some mask initially & then onclick of something you want to change that mask?

Comment: yes I want to change mask to  '999-999-9999'

Answer (score 1):

I'm considering you're using angular-formly. Here I don't think you can change config options on the go. So, to do that you've to delete the field from DOM & then reload it with new config option (e.g. mask). So, you can call method on click of any button, in which you can reset some boolean flag & then update config option & then set the flag.

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="vm.clickFn()">click</button>
```

Where clickFn can be:

```
vm.clickFn = function() {
   vm.show = false;
   vm.fields[0].templateOptions.mask = "999-999-9999";
   $timeout(function() {
     vm.show = true;
   });
}
```

Here timemout is just a small time to let it update the flag & run digest cycle.

**[Example](https://jsbin.com/munepoz/6/edit?html,js,output)** to refer.