# How to modify max value of fields' templateOptions in Formly in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formly

I would like to set a max value (templateOptions) of one of Formly fields depending on another fields values.
I wrote a function counting this value.
Regarding fields are initialized in constructor how can I modify max value of the field?

I tried setting value from the outer function getDiscountSo():

```
this.fields['sosnowiec.discount'].templateOptions.max = val;
```

but it doesn't affect fields max value.

```
{
  className: 'col-4',
  key: 'sosnowiec.discount',
  type: 'input',
  hideExpression: '!model.citySosnowiec' && '!model.sosnowiec.dayCount',
  templateOptions: {
  label: 'Discount',
  type: 'number',
  min: 0,
  max: this.getDiscountSo();
  required: true,
  },
},
```

This is my first post here, so I'll appreciate any advice about posting issues too.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code is not supposed to work. refer to this answer :[Formly update templateOptions on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856950/9369606)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Instead of function with if's I used regular expressions (:?) in chain and it works. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using regular expression in expressionOptions instead of a function and it worked. Problem solved.